# proper terms for tipper and dipper S articulation

Tags: english, phonetics, accent, american-english, articulation

I just learned for the first time from a [WIRED video about movie accents](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZSCGZphjq0) (at 4:30) that American English has multiple possible places of articulation for the "S" sound. I was able to find terms for these articulations used by speech therapists; if your tongue blade points to the alveolar ridge, you are a "tipper"; if it points down below your bottom teeth, you are a "dipper". Apparently an articulation in the middle also occurs in some speakers, but I did not see any specific terminology for this.

The standard "S" used in IPA is specified as a [voiceless alveolar fricative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolar_fricative#Voiceless_alveolar_sibilant), which I presume is what a tipper pronounces. What are the proper phonetic terms for the two other common "S" pronunciations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The technical terms in articulatory phonetics for "tipper" and "dipper" are **[apical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apical_consonant)** and **[laminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laminal_consonant)**.

They are both voiceless alveolar fricatives (IPA: [s]), but since "alveolar" only describes the passive place of articulation, voiceless alveolar fricatives can take many forms, as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolar_fricative) you linked to discusses in detail. Whenever the distinction is desired, they are called "apico-alveolar" and "lamino-alveolar" (or simply "apical alveolar" and "laminal alveolar") instead of just "alveolar". The apical and laminal [s] can be narrowly transcribed in IPA as [s̺] and [s̻], respectively.

According to [Ladefoged & Maddieson (1996](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/The+Sounds+of+the+World%27s+Languages-p-9780631198154): 146), "there is considerable disagreement among authorities as to which is the most common articulation", and "the apical-laminal distinction [is] not of particular importance in the characterization of the general, cross-speaker, properties of English **s**".

Comment: I think 'dipper' refers to the dental area (down below your bottom teeth). It is the passive articulation which is evoked.

Comment: @amegnunsen I don't think so. Both the Wired video and [these](https://pammarshalla.com/s-therapy-dippers-and-tippers/) [sites](https://nspt4kids.com/parenting/tipper-vs-dipper-how-to-produce-s-and-z-speech-sounds-north-shore-pediatric-therapy/) which discuss "tipper" and "dipper" articulations of alveolar fricatives talk about the distinction being allophonic. If they were talking about passive places of articulation, that would probably count as some kind of lisp and speech therapists would consider the "dipper" incorrect.

Comment: I agree with @amegnunsen. I articulate with the tongue dipped down by the lower teeth and gums. It makes sense to me.

Comment: @NateGlenn As I understand it, amegnunsen is saying that s/he thinks "dipper" refers to a dental (=passive) place of articulation – which is different from an articulation "with the tongue dipped down by the lower teeth and gums", which is just a laminal alveolar articulation. So it seems to me you actually *don't* agree with amegnunsen.

Comment: But isn't the so-called 'dipper' /s/ often apico-dental?

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Says who? Dental is the place of articulation of /θ/ and /ð/. Articulations that are described as laminal alveolar or laminal dental are often "denti-alveolar", meaning the alveolar ridge and the teeth share the place of the most constriction (or the difference is tenuous or variable as to which has the most constriction) because naturally it is difficult if not impossible to make turbulent noise with the tongue blade at the alveolar ridge but *not* simultaneously behind the teeth.

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut So while "lamino-dental" is a plausible description of an articulation of /s/, "apico-dental", AFAICT, is not and would most likely be considered as, and sound like, having a lisp, because it's essentially the sound of /θ/.

Comment: Caveat: my answer and comments presuppose that the allophony discussed in the Wired video—which I'm sure refers to the apical-laminal distinction discussed in Ladefoged & Maddieson—and the "tipper"/"dipper" distinction Nate found describe the same thing. I assume this is accurate because of the sites I linked to above, but there's a chance this usage is not commonly shared and some may refer by "tipper" or "dipper" to an articulation considered out of the norm, i.e. some type of lisp.